# Handling Slow Page Load Times in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, syncfusion

In a sample Xamarin Forms Prism application, I navigate from `MainPage` to `Page2` using the following code:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("Page2");
```

If `Page2` contains a Syncfusion control (say, something like the tab view), I have noticed that there is a substantial delay before that page transistion occurs. This is certainly more noticiable on older hardware. I have also noticed that the title in the navigation bar changes immediately, well before the page is rendered.

What is causing such a delay? Is there a way that I can toss up some type of *loading* message until right before the page is ready to render?

**UPDATE**

Here is some code...

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="StackOverflow.Views.MainPage" Title="{Binding Title}">
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Command="{Binding NavigateToPage2Command}" Text="Navigate to Page 2" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Navigation;

namespace StackOverflow.ViewModels
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
        {
            Title = "Main Page";

            NavigateToPage2Command = new DelegateCommand(NavigateToPage2CommandExecute);
        }

        public DelegateCommand NavigateToPage2Command
        {
            get;

            set;
        }

        public async void NavigateToPage2CommandExecute()
        {
            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("Page2");

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**Page2.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:sf="clr- namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.TabView;assembly=Syncfusion.SfTabView.XForms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="StackOverflow.Views.Page2" Title="{Binding Title}">
    <sf:SfTabView>
        <sf:SfTabItem Title="Tab 1" />
        <sf:SfTabItem Title="Tab 2" />
        <sf:SfTabItem Title="Tab 3" />
        <sf:SfTabItem Title="Tab 4" />
        <sf:SfTabItem Title="Tab 5" />
    </sf:SfTabView>
</ContentPage>
```

**Page2ViewModel.cs**

```
using Prism.Navigation;

namespace StackOverflow.ViewModels
{
    public class Page2ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public Page2ViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
        {
            Title = "Page 2";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a loading property in your view model, initially true. Then have a label saying loading and its IsVisible is bound to the vms IsLoading.  Likewise you can bind the syncfusions IsVisible to the same IsLoading, and use a converter which negates the boolean.

Answer (score 0):

What is causing the delay specifically is very hard to say since we don't actually have the code from your app. That said typically this occurs because you are blocking something. There are a few ways this might occur.

Assuming you're using Prism 7.2 you might be using IInitialize with some synchronous code that is taking a while to complete. Similarly you may be using IInitializeAsync and have a long running task that is causing the delay before `Page2` is pushed onto the Navigation Stack.

If you are currently using an older version of Prism then you may be using OnNavigatingTo (which is no longer supported in 7.2), and would be equivalent to IInitialize.

You may also be using IConfirmNavigation/IConfirmNavigationAsync which could similarly be causing delays.

As for how to properly handle this there are a few options... If you're ok with a visible UI update once your initialization has occurred, you could use an `async void` with `IInitialize.Initialize`. You may also want to implement a busy property in your MainPageViewModel and implement IConfirmNavigation (assuming you haven't already) and set IsBusy to true so that you can make some sort of Loading indicator visible on MainPage.

Comment: I updated the original question to include some code. I am not using anything *fancy* (yet). The delay seems to occur the first time I navigate from the main page to the second page. If I navigate back to the main page and then once again navigate to the second page, the delay is much shorter, almost unnoticeable on better hardware. I mention the last bit only because the devices we are targeting are using older hardware and Kit Kat is the latest that it will support. The delay is much more noticeable on these devices.

Comment: Continuing my last comment, there is a *flurry* of activity in the debug output the first time I navigate to the second page. On subsequent navigation to the second page, this activity in the debug output does not occur.

Comment: If you comment out the SfTabView does the problem persist?

Comment: No. Also, if I replace the tab view with something like, say, a stock button, it renders immediately without issue. This certainly seems to be related to the Syncfusion control. Looking at the debug output, it appears that it is trying to load a handful of references on the first navigation (which seems to make sense why the delay does not occur on subsequent navigations). I was not sure if this is a Syncfusion thing or could occur with other controls. Either way, I was curious as to whether or not there is a *recommended* strategy for handling such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I am an syncfusion employee.I tried replicating the issue in Moto E device with Android sdk 19.The load time was quite small.I could not attach a video for this since screen recording apps are not supported in sdk 19.If the load time is high in your device, could you please provide the device details so that we could help you better.The Answer by Andy sounds promising as well if heavy UIs are loaded.